# Can multiple users share 1 email address with different login credentials?

Tags: email, webserver, email-client

This may seem a daft question but there is a good reason behind it...

Is there a way for multiple users to share 1 email address with different logins?

For example,

Email address: info@superuser.com

username | password: jack1 | password123, jill2 | password, henry3 | password

I don't expect the normal Hotmail, Gmail to be able to do this. I was thinking more along the lines of configuring a email server.

Answer (score 5):

Gmail has a feature called [Email Delegation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en), which allows you to grant access to your account to other gmail addresses. They won't be able to change any major settings like change your password or change your recovery info but they can go to your inbox and read/reply/delete emails with their account.

With this, you can achieve the same purpose.

This is just some additional info though this doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It will not be possible the way you are asking

But following is how companies set this up.

If all the users are required they need unique email address and unique mailbox on your email server. So following would be separate mailboxes

username | password: jack1 | password123, jill2 | password, henry3 | password

Then following can be a shared mailbox or just an alias 
email address: info@superuser.com

- if you want you can give permission to your shared mailbox to the above mentioned users and then they can link their outlook or other email clients to it so they can view this mailbox as well as their regular mailbox
- if it's an alias or distribution list then you just need to add those users as part of the list and they will get all the emails forwarded to their mailboxes